# How to bootstrap 4 space column by column 5px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z5XQ.png)[how to bootstap 4 space column by column 5px?]

How to bootstrap 4 space column by column 5px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to configure the Bootstrap 4 Grid gutter spacing to a specific width (5px) is to **set `$grid-gutter-width: 5px;` and re-compile SASS files**.

The [Bootstrap theming documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/) has much more details on how to work with the SASS files.